# RxJava: database and remote server

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have a list of objects that I want retrieve from a local database (if available), or from a remote server otherwise. I'm using RxJava Observables (SqlBrite for the database and Retrofit for the remote server).

My query code is as follows:

```
Observable<List<MyObject>> dbObservable = mDatabase
            .createQuery(MyObject.TABLE_NAME,MyObject.SELECT_TYPE_A)
            .mapToList(MyObject.LOCAL_MAPPER);
Observable<List<MyObject>> remoteObservable = mRetrofitService.getMyObjectApiService().getMyObjects();

return Observable.concat(dbObservable, remoteObservable)
    .first(new Func1<List<MyObject>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(List<MyObject> myObjects) {
                    return !myObjects.isEmpty();
                }
            });
```

I see the first observable running and hitting the first method with an empty list, but then the retrofit observable does not run, there is no network request. If I switch the order of the observables, or just return the remote observable, it works as expected, it hits the remote server and returns the list of objects.

Why would the remote observable fail to run in this scenario? The subscriber's onNext, orError and onComplete methods are not called when I concatenate the observables with the db first and retrofit second.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kaushik Gopal has addressed this in his [RxJava-Android-Samples](https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples/blob/605dc13e1e60ec45343c342f20d57a9e69edade5/README.md#retrieve-data-first-from-a-cache-then-a-network-call) github project.

He recommends using this technique:

```
getFreshNetworkData()
          .publish(network ->
                         Observable.merge(network,
                                          getCachedDiskData().takeUntil(network)))
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<MyObject>() {

              ...
          });
```

In your case, it might look like this:

```
remoteObservable
      .publish(network ->
                     Observable.merge(network,
                                      dbObservable.takeUntil(network)))
      .first(myObjects -> !myObjects.isEmpty());
```

**Edit:** It sounds like you just might need this:

```
dbObservable
    .flatMap(localResult -> {
        if (localResult.isEmpty()) {
            return remoteObservable;
        } else {
            return Observable.just(localResult);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution works well if I want to hit the network for fresh data for each request, but in my case the cached items have an expiry date, so I only want to hit the network if the items were never cached, or if they're expired. My DB query will return an empty list in that scenario (not cached or expired), so I'd like to have a means to run the 2nd observable only if the first returned an empty list. I though the first() operator with a conditional function would do it, but the network observable is never run in my original code, even when the cache is empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I edited my post. See if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks, this works and is a concise solution. I still do not understand why my original solution does not work and thus I need to look into it, but this solution fits my needs nicely. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have your observables which can get data from your local and remote like below:

```
        final Observable<Page> localResult = mSearchLocalDataSource.search(query);
        final Observable<Page> remoteResult = mSearchRemoteDataSource.search(query)
                .doOnNext(new Action1<Page>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Page page) {
                        if (page != null) {
                            mSearchLocalDataSource.save(query, page);
                            mResultCache.put(query, page);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Then you can map them and get first which means if local available use local if not use remote:

```
        return Observable.concat(localResult, remoteResult)
                .first()
                .map(new Func1<Page, Page>() {
                    @Override
                    public Page call(Page page) {
                        if (page == null) {
                            throw new NoSuchElementException("No result found!");
                        }
                        return page;
                    }
                });
```

And subscribe it like below:

```
mCompositeSubscription.clear();
        final Subscription subscription = mSearchRepository.search(this.mQuery)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<Page>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        // Completed
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        mView.onDefaultMessage(e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Page page) {
                        mView.onDefaultMessage(page.getContent());
                    }
                });

        mCompositeSubscription.add(subscription);
```

For more detail or example you can check my github repo: 
https://github.com/savepopulation/wikilight

Good luck!

Edit:

You can try a local observable like below. Simply it checks if there's a record and returns an empty observable.

```
@Override
public Observable<Page> search(@NonNull final String query) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Page>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Page> subscriber) {
            final Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(mRealmConfiguration);
            final Page page = realm.where(Page.class)
                    .equalTo("query", query)
                    .findFirst();
            if (page != null && page.isLoaded() && page.isValid()) {
                Log.i("data from", "realm");
                subscriber.onNext(realm.copyFromRealm(page));
            } else {
                Observable.empty();
            }
            subscriber.onCompleted();
            realm.close();
        }
    });
}
```

Edit 2:

When you return null from local concat and first will not work and your remote will not be called because null means observable returns null but still can observe. When you return observable.empty with concat and first this means observable cannot emit anything from local more and so it can emit from remote.

Comment: Thanks, this is similar to what I've tried, but as written here it won't work because we are using the first() operator unconditionally, we will always return the result from the database, even if it's empty (the database operator always calls onNext, if there is nothing in the DB it simply returns an empty list, but onNext is still called), so the first() operator will prevent the network observable from running.

Comment: i'm not sure if understand you correctly but i edited my answer. if you return empty observable from db if there's no record network call gets called.

Comment: This solution would work (though that call to Observable.empty() is redundant). However, I'd like to understand why using concat with first(condition) does not work as it's meant to.

Comment: i edited my answer. i think it'll answer your question.